# Plotting a family of equations

Tags: plotting

I want to plot a family of equations for different values of $C$. For example $x^2+y^2=C$. How?

I found out that this doesn't work:

```
ContourPlot[x^2 + y^2 == C /. C -> Range[0, 5], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}]
```

What will work?

Thanks!

Comment: What you're looking for is the option `Contours -> Range[0, 5]`. Get rid of the `== C` and add that option after the domain specification.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try mapping the plotting function over the range of interest. Like this:

```
Map[ContourPlot[x^2 + y^2 == #, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}] & , Range[0, 5]]
```

or in op form:

```
ContourPlot[x^2 + y^2 == #, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}] &  /@  Range[0, 5]
```

or all the plots together:

```
cplots = Map[  ContourPlot[x^2 + y^2 == #, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}] & , 
             Range[0, 5]]; 
Show[cplots]
```

Hope this helps
Cheers!

Comment: @Imre: I tried to answer your question using general functional programming concepts (in this case mapping a function over a range), keeping your code as intact as possible. Assuming that your code reflects your way to think about a problem, chances are that you may be able to apply this solution in different contexts. However, Belisarius' answer below is more idiomatic. (@march's comment also points out the use of Contours -> Range option).

Answer (score 4):

```
ContourPlot[x^2 + y^2, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, 
            Contours -> Range[0, 100, 10], ContourShading -> None]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: @Imre, belisarius: I think this is a better answer. More idiomatic and representative of the gazillion options packed in Wolframatica's high-level functions.

Comment: @paramecium Thanks. I also believe that. The problem with accepting non-optimal answers is that future users will get those as the "best" method available misguiding them. Anyway that happens a lot here. BTW, I alredy upvoted your answer :)